Export on Keycloak with large users
I want to export my Keycloak 21.0.2 with almost 300,000 users an import it in another Keycloak in another system. I run ./kc.sh export --dir exp. The exp folder generated with almost 6000 files named myrealm-users-*.json. But in import phase running ./kc.sh import --dir exp I found out that in some jsons I have duplicate users which fails the import phase.
Does any one have any suggestion? How can I solve this duplicate users?

What part of the user causes the error? If it is the ID, it seems to be an export error, if it is the email, you can try to disable the "Duplicate emails" switch in the realm settings (login tab)

I create random 300K users by node.js without duplicate username , create user for my-realm, create user by node.js, export, copy json to host, delete docker volume, start new keycloak v 21.0.2, copy jsons from host to container, import and re-start docker-compose then get end of 5 users by Postman with "/admin/realms/my-realm/users?first=299995&max=300000&enabled=true", get correct last 5 users. It means your username were duplicated original Keycloak. Not an import/export issue.

@csbrogi
Thanks for your reply. Yes, the whole user information is duplicate. For example in file myrealm-users-61.json, In the last element, I have a user with ID "120" and username "user120" with specific firstname, lastname and attributes. In file myrealm-users-62.json, the first element is this user with the same ID, username, firstname, lastname, and the same attributes. I don't know why this happen. I only use ./kc.sh export --dir exp

@BenchVue The problem is that when I search for the user which is duplicate in my database or keycloak services to get a specific user, there is only one record related to the one duplicate username. But in my exports json files, I have almost 100 users where there are an only record in my db but duplicates in jsons. As an example, in file myrealm-users-61.json, In the last element, I have a user with specific ID, username, firstname, lastname and attributes. In file myrealm-users-62.json, the first element is this user with the same ID, username, firstname, lastname, and the same attributes.

if you add duplicated username, the Keycloak UI  error message "Could not create user: User exists with same username", how to duplicate user? that one duplicate username whatever you did. it may be possible to create json more duplicate username when you export. So the true of source was wrong in Keycloak of database. So more username duplicate by export is side effect. Not a export issue, you need to remove duplicated username in Keycloak. Then try again to export. My experimental is no problem to export 300K username without duplicate in v21.0.2. If you want to prove I can show my steps.

You can take a look at your database.
something like
select count(), email from user_entity where realm_id ='realm' group by email having count() > 1;

@BenchVue  I don't have duplicate users. For better explanation, imagine I have a user with ID "1", username "user1", firstname "user1f", and lastname "user1l". It is the only user registered by this username and ID in my database. But when I call export command, I have 2 json file like myrealm-users-61.json and myrealm-users-62.json where the last element of myrealm-users-61.json and the first element of myrealm-users-62.json are completely the same having the information of "user1". Again I emphasize that I have only one "user1" in my database!

@csbrogi  I don't have duplicate users. For better explanation, imagine I have a user with ID "1", username "user1", firstname "user1f", and lastname "user1l". It is the only user registered by this username and ID in my database. But when I call export command, I have 2 json file like myrealm-users-61.json and myrealm-users-62.json where the last element of myrealm-users-61.json and the first element of myrealm-users-62.json are completely the same having the information of "user1". Again I emphasize that I have only one "user1" in my database!

I create program scan all 6000 json files and count unique usernames. each json has 50 username. The result is 300,000. exactly matched with expectation. There are no duplicated username. From "my-realm-users-0.json" to "my-realm-users-5999.json". My export result of all 300K usernames no duplicated at all.

@BenchVue I checked my users. I have 358000 users. This time ./kc.sh export --dir tmp2 --users different_files --users-per-file 200. Again I have 50 duplicate IDs which are not the same IDs as I ran ./kc.sh export --dir tmp1 few days ago. This shows that the database has not duplicate users as the export duplicate IDs changes only by changing the number of users-per-file!

I will try it with 358000 users in tonight. Give me a time.

@b0w92, I tested 358,000 users and there are no duplicated username, I posted my steps can you try it? And let me know my steps result.

I tested with 358,000 users export/import but no error and no duplicated export json files.
Here is my steps

Step 0: preparations
Install Docker Desktop on windows in here
Install node.js in here
node -v
v18.20.4

Install node.js dependencies
package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^9.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.9",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "exceljs": "^4.4.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "p-limit": "^6.1.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "qs": "^6.13.1"
  }
}

npm install


save_excel.js
const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');

const USER_COUNT = 358000;
const FILE_NAME = 'Users.xlsx';

// Sets to store used usernames and emails
const usedUsernames = new Set();
const usedEmails = new Set();

// Function to capitalize the first letter of a string
const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

// Function to create a random user with a unique username and email
const createRandomUser = (index) => {
    let username, email;

    do {
        username = faker.internet.username().toLowerCase();
        if (usedUsernames.has(username)) {
            username += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
        }
    } while (usedUsernames.has(username));
    usedUsernames.add(username);

    do {
        email = faker.internet.email().toLowerCase();
        if (usedEmails.has(email)) {
            email = email.split('@')[0] + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + '@' + email.split('@')[1];
        }
    } while (usedEmails.has(email));
    usedEmails.add(email);

    return {
        username: username,
        password: `${username}_1234`.toLowerCase(),
        reset: ((index % 2) ? true : false),
        firstName: capitalizeFirstLetter(faker.person.firstName()),
        lastName: capitalizeFirstLetter(faker.person.lastName()),
        email: email
    };
}

// Function to write users to Excel file
const saveUsersToExcel = async (users) => {
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Users');

    // Define columns
    worksheet.columns = [
        { header: 'Username', key: 'username', width: 30 },
        { header: 'Password', key: 'password', width: 30 },
        { header: 'Reset Password', key: 'reset', width: 15 },
        { header: 'First Name', key: 'firstName', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Last Name', key: 'lastName', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Email', key: 'email', width: 50 }
    ];

    // Sort users by username
    users.sort((a, b) => a.username.localeCompare(b.username));

    // Add users to the worksheet
    worksheet.addRows(users);

    // Save workbook
    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(FILE_NAME);
    console.log(`Saved ${users.length} users to ${FILE_NAME}`);
}

// Main function to create users and save to Excel
const main = async () => {
    let users = [];

    for (let index = 0; index < USER_COUNT; index++) {
        users.push(createRandomUser(index));
    }

    await saveUsersToExcel(users);
}

main().catch(err => console.error(err));

Run it
node save_excel.js

Result
Users.xlsx


docker-compose.yml
version: '3.6'

services:
  keycloak_web:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.2
    container_name: keycloak_web
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://keycloakdb:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8080
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: start-dev
    depends_on:
      - keycloakdb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  keycloakdb:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

volumes:
  postgres_data:

detail in here
Create myrealm

Extend master token 1 day

create_user.js
(async () => {
    const axios = require('axios');
    const qs = require('qs');
    const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
    const pLimit = (await import('p-limit')).default;

    // Limit concurrency to 10 requests at a time
    const limit = pLimit(10);

    // Keycloak details
    const client_id = 'admin-cli';
    const user_name = 'admin';
    const pass_word = 'admin';
    const grant_type = 'password';
    const tokenURL = 'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token';

    const usersEndpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/myrealm/users';

    // Read from Excel file
    async function readExcelFile() {
        try {
            const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
            await workbook.xlsx.readFile('Users.xlsx');
            const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Users');
            if (!worksheet) throw new Error("Worksheet 'Users' not found");

            let users = [];
            worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: false }, (row, rowNumber) => {
                if (rowNumber !== 1) { // Skipping header row
                    users.push({
                        username: row.getCell(1).value,
                        firstName: row.getCell(4).value,
                        lastName: row.getCell(5).value,
                        email: row.getCell(6).value
                    });
                }
            });
            return users;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error reading Excel file:', error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    let tokenDetails = { token: null, expiry: 0 }; // Store token and expiry time

    // Function to get a new token
    async function getToken() {
        const data = qs.stringify({
            client_id: client_id,
            username: user_name,
            password: pass_word,
            grant_type: grant_type
        });

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        };

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(tokenURL, data, config);
            const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Current time in seconds
            tokenDetails.token = response.data.access_token;
            tokenDetails.expiry = currentTime + response.data.expires_in; // Calculate expiry time
            return tokenDetails.token;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching token:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    // Function to ensure the token is valid
    async function ensureToken() {
        const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        if (!tokenDetails.token || currentTime >= tokenDetails.expiry) {
            console.log('Refreshing token...');
            return await getToken();
        }
        return tokenDetails.token;
    }

    async function createUserInKeycloak(user) {
        let attempts = 0;
        const maxAttempts = 3;

        while (attempts < maxAttempts) {
            try {
                const token = await ensureToken(); // Ensure token is valid
                const response = await axios.post(
                    usersEndpoint,
                    {
                        username: user.username,
                        email: user.email,
                        firstName: user.firstName,
                        lastName: user.lastName,
                        requiredActions: [],
                        emailVerified: true,
                        groups: [],
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                        }
                    }
                );

                return response; // Success
            } catch (error) {
                attempts++;
                if (error.response && error.response.status === 401 && attempts < maxAttempts) {
                    console.warn(`Retrying for user ${user.username} (${attempts}/${maxAttempts})...`);
                } else {
                    console.error(
                        `Error creating user ${user.username}:`,
                        error.response ? error.response.data : error.message
                    );
                    return null; // Failure
                }
            }
        }
    }

    async function processBatch(users, successCount) {
        const tasks = users.map(user =>
            limit(async () => {
                const response = await createUserInKeycloak(user);
                if (response) {
                    successCount.count++;
                    console.log(`Current total users added: ${successCount.count} | User created: ${user.username}`);
                }
            })
        );
        await Promise.all(tasks); // Wait for all tasks to complete
    }

    async function main() {
        try {
            const batchSize = 10000;
            const users = await readExcelFile();
            let successCount = { count: 0 }; // Use an object to maintain reference across batches

            for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i += batchSize) {
                const batch = users.slice(i, i + batchSize);
                console.log(`Processing batch ${i / batchSize + 1}...`);
                await processBatch(batch, successCount);
            }

            console.log(`All users have been processed. Total users added: ${successCount.count}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
        }
    }

    main();
})();

Run it
node create_user.js

Result



GO inside Keycloak docker container
docker exec -it keycloak_web bash

Create tmp2 directory under /bin directory
cd /opt/keycloak/bin
mkdir tmp2

./kc.sh export --dir tmp2 --users different_files --users-per-file 200

Result


copy-json.js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const containerName = 'keycloak_web';
const sourcePath = '/opt/keycloak/bin/tmp2';
const destinationPath = './tmp2';

// Ensure the destination directory exists
if (!fs.existsSync(destinationPath)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(destinationPath, { recursive: true });
}

// Function to execute a shell command
function runCommand(command) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(stderr || error.message);
            } else {
                resolve(stdout.trim());
            }
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Fetching JSON file list from container...');
        const fileList = await runCommand(
            `docker exec ${containerName} sh -c "ls ${sourcePath} | grep \\.json"`
        );
        const files = fileList.split('\n');

        console.log(`Found ${files.length} files. Starting copy...`);

        for (const file of files) {
            const sourceFile = `${sourcePath}/${file}`;
            const destinationFile = path.join(destinationPath, file);

            console.log(`Copying ${file}...`);
            await runCommand(`docker cp ${containerName}:${sourceFile} ${destinationFile}`);
        }

        console.log('All files have been copied successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    }
})();

From CMD terminal
mkdir tmp2
node copy-json.js

Result


Count unique and duplicated username
user-count-from-jsons.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Directory containing the JSON files
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'tmp2');

async function countUsernames() {
    try {
        const usernameCounts = new Map();

        // Read all files in the directory
        const files = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath);

        for (const file of files) {
            if (file.startsWith('myrealm-users-') && file.endsWith('.json')) {
                const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, file);

                // Read and parse the JSON file
                const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8'));

                // Count occurrences of each username
                for (const user of data.users) {
                    const username = user.username;
                    usernameCounts.set(username, (usernameCounts.get(username) || 0) + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        // Calculate total unique and duplicate usernames
        let duplicateCount = 0;
        for (const [username, count] of usernameCounts) {
            if (count > 1) {
                duplicateCount += (count - 1); // Count duplicates for this username
            }
        }

        console.log(`Total unique usernames: ${usernameCounts.size}`);
        console.log(`Total duplicate usernames: ${duplicateCount}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
    }
}

countUsernames();

Result


Terminate container
docker compose down

Clean Volume
The volume name is depend on your working directory

It will clean all of users
Run docker Keycloak again
docker compose up -d

You can check all of users is cleaned in Keycloak UI
Go again Keycloak container with root user
docker exec -u root -it keycloak_web /bin/bash

Create tmp2 directory under /bin
cd /opt/keycloak/bin
mkdir tmp2

From CMD terminal
copy-to-container.js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const containerName = 'keycloak_web'; // Replace with your container name
const destinationPath = '/opt/keycloak/bin/tmp2'; // Destination path inside the container
const sourcePath = './tmp2'; // Source path on the host containing files to copy

// Ensure the source directory exists
if (!fs.existsSync(sourcePath)) {
    console.error(`Source directory does not exist: ${sourcePath}`);
    process.exit(1);
}

// Function to execute a shell command
function runCommand(command) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(stderr || error.message);
            } else {
                resolve(stdout.trim());
            }
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Fetching file list from source directory: ${sourcePath}`);
        const files = fs.readdirSync(sourcePath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.json'));

        if (files.length === 0) {
            console.log('No JSON files found in the source directory.');
            return;
        }

        console.log(`Found ${files.length} files. Starting copy to container...`);

        for (const file of files) {
            const sourceFile = path.join(sourcePath, file);
            const containerDestination = `${containerName}:${destinationPath}/${file}`;

            console.log(`Copying ${file} to container...`);
            await runCommand(`docker cp "${sourceFile}" "${containerDestination}"`);
        }

        console.log('All files have been copied successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    }
})();

Run it
node copy-to-container.js

Result


Go /bin directory
docker exec -u root -it keycloak_web /bin/bash
cd /opt/keycloak/bin

Import the jsons
./kc.sh import --dir tmp2

Result

Check unique usernames number by node.js
user-count-by-api.js
const axios = require('axios');

// Keycloak details
const keycloakServer = 'http://localhost:8080';
const realm = 'myrealm';
const client_id = 'admin-cli';
const username = 'admin';
const password = 'admin';
const grant_type = 'password';

// Token endpoint
const tokenURL = `${keycloakServer}/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

// User count endpoint
const userCountURL = `${keycloakServer}/admin/realms/${realm}/users/count`;

// Function to fetch Keycloak token
async function getToken() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            tokenURL,
            new URLSearchParams({
                client_id: client_id,
                username: username,
                password: password,
                grant_type: grant_type,
            }),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
            }
        );

        return response.data.access_token;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching token:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

// Function to get user count
async function getUserCount(token) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(userCountURL, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        });

        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user count:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

// Main function
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Fetching Keycloak token...');
        const token = await getToken();

        console.log('Fetching user count...');
        const userCount = await getUserCount(token);

        console.log(`Total users in realm "${realm}": ${userCount}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
    }
})();

Result

Confirm it
Search end of user from JSON and Keycloak UI
In UI, other two users "zula99" is in email
The "zula99" username is unique.


Conclusion
Count unique username number 358,000 is by REST API
Count unique username number 358,000 is by scanning jsons
There are no duplicated username for exporting/importing function in Keycloak version 21.0.2

Thank you for your time and for your help. I finally identified the problem. My Keycloak server is a live server where users continuously register throughout the day and night. I was exporting the database while registrations were occurring, which caused inconsistencies and duplicates in my export.

OK, no problem to experiment this issue spending my time, I am also learn a lot from your problem. I am happy to hear you figured out your database already duplicated a username. It may be filter out after exported JSON files to remove duplicated usernames before import by special handling filter out program. If you want it I can make it.
